# Transform output \theoremstyle{remark} from italics to bold

Tags: theorems

I'm using `\theoremstyle{remark}` To make my cheatsheet.

The output of the `\theoremstyle{remark}` is the one I need, because it doesn't create any space between the defintion.
The problem is that the intro of `\theoremstyle{remark}` is in italics, while I would like to have it in bold.

[image]

In this case, T 3.51; D 3.52 and T3.53 should be in bold.

This is the code

```
\documentclass[9pt,landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{color,graphicx,overpic}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,latexsym,ifthen}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% useful macros
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{theorem}{T}[section]

\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{C}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{D}
\newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%[section]
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{notation}{Notation}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\providecommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\providecommand{\norm}[1]{{\lVert#1\rVert}}

\def\NN{\mathbb{N}}
\def\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}
\def\QQ{\mathbb{Q}}
\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}

\newcommand{\fat}[1]{\text{\boldmath$#1$}}


\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{[\arabic{footnote}]}

\pdfinfo{
  /Title (example.pdf)
  /Creator (TeX)
  /Producer (pdfTeX 1.40.0)
  /Author (Seamus)
  /Subject (Example)
  /Keywords (pdflatex, latex,pdftex,tex)}

% This sets page margins to .5 inch if using letter paper, and to 1cm
% if using A4 paper. (This probably isn't strictly necessary.)
% If using another size paper, use default 1cm margins.

    \ifthenelse{ \lengthtest{ \paperwidth = 297mm}}
        {\geometry{top=0.2cm,left=0.2cm,right=0.2cm,bottom=0.2cm} }
        {\geometry{top=0.2cm,left=0.2cm,right=0.2cm,bottom=0.2cm} }
    

\titleformat*{\section}{\normal\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Small\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{5pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{5pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

% Turn off header and footer
\pagestyle{empty}


\setcounter{section}{1}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.5ex}


\begin{document}
\raggedright
\footnotesize
\begin{multicols}{4}


% multicol parameters
% These lengths are set only within the two main columns
%\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.25pt}
\setlength{\premulticols}{1pt}
\setlength{\postmulticols}{1pt}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.2pt}

\section*{1 Numbers}
\subsection*{Natural Numbers}

\iffalse
\begin{definition}
We denote the set of \emph{natural numbers} by $\NN:=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$.
\end{definition}
\fi

\textbf{PeanoAxioms}\\
- 1 is natural number\\
- If n is a natural number, then its also $n'=n+1$\\
- 1 is not the successor of any natural number\\
- two natural numbers have same successor, then $n = m$\\
- a subset that contains 1 and successor $n'$ of any of its elements n, must be n itself.

\iffalse
\begin{definition}\label{definition:n-factorial}
For $n\in\NN$, the product of the numbers from 1 to $n$ is called ``\emph{n factorial}'',
$
  n! := \prod_{k=1}^n k.
$
\end{definition}
\fi

\begin{definition}\label{definition:binomial-coefficient}
For $n\in\NN$ and $k=0,1,\dots,n$, we define the \emph{binomial coefficient}
$
  \binom{n}{k} := \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}.
$
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
\emph{integers} $\ZZ:=\{0,1,-1,2,-2,\dots\}$.
\end{definition}
\rule{0.3\linewidth}{0.25pt}
\scriptsize
\bibliographystyle{abstract}
\bibliography{refFile}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to transform the italics of remark into bold? I can't use plain or other because they insert a spacing before and after each.

Thanks

Comment: Pleas cleanup your MWE. You twice loaded `amsmath ...` etc. Also omit all packages and your definition which arn't relevant to your problem.

Comment: You don't need to use `\theoremstyle{remark}` twice. Every theorem like below it will be in `remark` style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Andrew Swann’s answer is probably what I too would do in practice.  Having said that, I think that, for future reference, it is fair to mention as well the fact that the *amsthm* package lets you define new theorem styles, by means of the `\newtheoremstyle` command.  From a “theoretical” point of view, this approach is perhaps neater, and surely more general.

For a full reference on the `\newtheoremstyle` command, see the documentation of the *amsthm* package.  The following code illustrates how it could be used in our case:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{boldremark}
    {\dimexpr\topsep/2\relax} % space above
    {\dimexpr\topsep/2\relax} % space below
    {}          % body font
    {}          % indent amount
    {\bfseries} % theorem head font
    {.}         % punctuation after theorem head
    {.5em}      % space after theorem head
    {}          % theorem hed spec. (empty = "normal")

\theoremstyle{boldremark}
\newtheorem{brem}{T}[section] % remarks are numbered within sections



\begin{document}
\section{\emph{Very} elementary mathematics}
Some text before the remark.
\begin{brem}
    It is well known that\[1+1=2\mbox{.}\]
\end{brem}
Some text after the remark.
\end{document}
```

This is what the output looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`amsthm.sty` contains

```
\def\th@remark{%
  \thm@headfont{\itshape}%
  \normalfont % body font
  \thm@preskip\topsep \divide\thm@preskip\tw@
  \thm@postskip\thm@preskip
}
```

so you can copy this and replace `\itshape` by `\bfseries`.  You have to include the resulting code between `\makeatletter...\makeatother` because of the `@` in the macro names.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[9pt,landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{color,graphicx,overpic}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,latexsym,ifthen}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% useful macros
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatletter
\def\th@remark{%
  \thm@headfont{\bfseries}%
  \normalfont % body font
  \thm@preskip\topsep \divide\thm@preskip\tw@
  \thm@postskip\thm@preskip
}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{theorem}{T}[section]

\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{C}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{D}
\newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%[section]
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{notation}{Notation}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\providecommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\providecommand{\norm}[1]{{\lVert#1\rVert}}

\def\NN{\mathbb{N}}
\def\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}
\def\QQ{\mathbb{Q}}
\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}

\newcommand{\fat}[1]{\text{\boldmath$#1$}}


\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{[\arabic{footnote}]}

\pdfinfo{
  /Title (example.pdf)
  /Creator (TeX)
  /Producer (pdfTeX 1.40.0)
  /Author (Seamus)
  /Subject (Example)
  /Keywords (pdflatex, latex,pdftex,tex)}

% This sets page margins to .5 inch if using letter paper, and to 1cm
% if using A4 paper. (This probably isn't strictly necessary.)
% If using another size paper, use default 1cm margins.

    \ifthenelse{ \lengthtest{ \paperwidth = 297mm}}
        {\geometry{top=0.2cm,left=0.2cm,right=0.2cm,bottom=0.2cm} }
        {\geometry{top=0.2cm,left=0.2cm,right=0.2cm,bottom=0.2cm} }


\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\small\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{5pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{5pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

% Turn off header and footer
\pagestyle{empty}


\setcounter{section}{1}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.5ex}


\begin{document}
\raggedright
\footnotesize
\begin{multicols}{4}


% multicol parameters
% These lengths are set only within the two main columns
%\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.25pt}
\setlength{\premulticols}{1pt}
\setlength{\postmulticols}{1pt}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.2pt}

\section*{1 Numbers}
\subsection*{Natural Numbers}

\iffalse
\begin{definition}
We denote the set of \emph{natural numbers} by $\NN:=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$.
\end{definition}
\fi

\textbf{PeanoAxioms}\\
- 1 is natural number\\
- If n is a natural number, then its also $n'=n+1$\\
- 1 is not the successor of any natural number\\
- two natural numbers have same successor, then $n = m$\\
- a subset that contains 1 and successor $n'$ of any of its elements n, must be n itself.

\iffalse
\begin{definition}\label{definition:n-factorial}
For $n\in\NN$, the product of the numbers from 1 to $n$ is called ``\emph{n factorial}'',
$
  n! := \prod_{k=1}^n k.
$
\end{definition}
\fi

\begin{definition}\label{definition:binomial-coefficient}
For $n\in\NN$ and $k=0,1,\dots,n$, we define the \emph{binomial coefficient}
$
  \binom{n}{k} := \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}.
$
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
\emph{integers} $\ZZ:=\{0,1,-1,2,-2,\dots\}$.
\end{definition}
\rule{0.3\linewidth}{0.25pt}
\scriptsize
\bibliographystyle{abstract}
\bibliography{refFile}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```